# Three.js faces/vertices cut off but Bounding Box correct

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using [BufferGeometry](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-custom-buffergeometry.html) to handle meshes with lots of vertices, faces and normals, which I supply via [TypedArrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray). During rendering, the `Scene` and its `Mesh` is constructed without any warnings or errors in the console. With [BoxHelper](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/helpers/BoxHelper) I've constructed a Bounding Box around the mesh.

Now the strangest thing happens: Although the Bounding Box is **perfectly correct**, the faces/vertices are **cut off** somewhere in the middle.

To see what I mean, here is the comparison of two models rendered with a python script (left) and rendered with Three.js (right):

[image]

[image]

The code I've used for this task can be found [here in this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/7rEfQsJC). Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I found my mistake. `itemSize` of `BufferAttribute` for the faces has to be **1**.

So I've changed this line

```
geometry.setIndex( new THREE.Uint32BufferAttribute(faces, 3) );
```

to

```
geometry.setIndex( new THREE.Uint32BufferAttribute(faces, 1) );
```

More info about this constructor parameter can be found [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/bufferAttributeTypes/BufferAttributeTypes).